# Dell S6000/FTOS Switch - Setting up route between IP on port-channel interface and management network

Tags: routing, switch, dell

I have a Dell S6000 switch running FTOS 9.7. On my network I have a VM on a Centos box at 172.16.45.212, port-channel 113, vlan 671 on the switch. It's running Check_MK. I need to give it access to both my DDN storage cluster heads at 172.16.85.100 and .200. However, the catch is that those two heads are on the S6000's management network 0/0, vlan 700.

How do I setup a route so that the VM can see the two DDN heads? I already tried:

```
management route 172.16.45.212/32 managementethernet
```

...and...

```
ip route 172.16.45.212/32 vlan 700
```

Neither worked. When I try to ping either of the DDN heads it says "Network unreachable."

(And yes, I am not a networking guru...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have received an answer from Dell (after waiting a week... not happy about that) and the answer is that it cannot be done without creating a mess. For the benefit of other people with the same question, this is the response I received from a senior networking engineer:

> The management interface is in a separated VRF instance and there is
>   no way of internally connecting the management to a VLAN interface.
>   Only option would be connect the management interface to another
>   switch and route back to a data interface on the switch. I would not
>   recommend doing this unless creating a L3 barrier or having a separate
>   VLAN. Force10 switches use the same mac address for the management and
>   data interfaces. If the mac address is seen in two different
>   interfaces in the same vlan, that will cause mac flapping and
>   connectivity problems.